# How to search Google Ngrams for "dated" words & phrases?

Tags: google-api, n-gram

I'd like to write an application that searches Google's Ngram data to return words and phrases that used to be more popular, by some arbitrary percentage, within some arbitrary range of years, than they are now.

For example: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cowabunga&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3

Ideally, I'd like to be able to **find** these words and phrases without specifying them up front. Can anyone help me come up with a way to do this using a downloaded copy of the Ngrams data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step after downloading some n-grams is to dump them into a [SQLite3 database](https://www.sqlite.org/). For example, I fetched the [1-grams starting with the letter 't'](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-t.gz)

To dump them into SQLite, run the command `sqlite3 1grams.db`

```
sqlite> create table t1grams (ngram text, year integer, match_count integer, volume_count integer);
sqlite> .separator "\t"
sqlite> .import googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-t t1grams
```

Second step is to pick the year range, call them `YEAR_START` and `YEAR_END`, and your percentage, call it `PERCENT_THRESHOLD`.

Your problem reduces to a query where you select those `ngram`s such that `match_count` is `PERCENT_THRESHOLD`% less common at `YEAR_END` than at `YEAR_START`.

Comment: @duncan-malashock if this sounds correct, I'll come up with an example SQL query to actually finish this computation. However, I want to make sure this aligns with what you are trying to find.

Comment: Hey, I am using mapreduce to do this task, can you please guide me in this regard??

Comment: @MuneebulHassan Not here, but there are good tutorials for this: http://hadooptutorial.info/mapreduce-use-case-for-n-gram-statistics/